# A bag contains 20 red marbles, 20 green marbles and 20 blue marbles. You grab 15 marbles. What is the probability of getting 5 of each color?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

While the colors are distinguishable from each other, the marbles themselves are all indistinguishable. The way I thought about it is that the sample space is the number of ways you can distribute 15 marbles to 3 different color "bins." Using stars and bars, this would be $\binom{15+3-1}{15} = \binom{17}{15}$. For the ways to get 5 of each color, I would take the 15 marbles and distribute 5 to each bin. This could be done in only 1 way. Would the final probability be $\frac{1}{136} = 0.00735294117$?

Comment: It's hard to use Stars and Bars for probability questions, as the outcomes counted by that method are not equally probable.

Comment: In your case, it is easy to count all the "good" selections, there are $\binom {20}5^3$ of them.  And it is easy to count the total number of selections, so...

Comment: Ahh ok that makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to know the probability of getting $5$ blue marbles out of $20$, $5$ green marbles out of $20$ and $5$ red marbles out of $20$. That is simply

$$\frac{\binom{20}{5}\binom{20}{5}\binom{20}{5}}{\binom{60}{15}}=0.07005964009$$

Comment: Thank you for your comment!

Comment: Of course. If this has solved your doubt, please mark the answer as correct.